# AngularJs: return a promise of nested $http - solution already found but why does it work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to build a nested $http.get, after the first succeed, then request the second.

then i came out with something like this:

```
$http.get('/xxx').then(function(response){
    $http.get('/yyy').then(function(response){
        //do something
    })
});
```

But i want to **return a Promise** after all, so that i can organise my code properly. Obviously the code above doesn't meet my need.

Then i did a lot research with `$q.all()`, but actually with $q.all, the second request doesn't wait for the first, **it will send second request even if the first request doesn't successfully response**.

After that i found a **solution**, which works like a charm in my case:

```
var promise = $http.get('/xxx').then(function(response1){
    return $http.get('/yyy').then(function(response2) {
        return response2.data;
    });;
});     
return promise;
```

But i don't understand why would it work???

In the success function of first promise($http.get), it returns the second promise as the parameter of the function for then().

but if i call

```
promise.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

i found the data printed here is **response2.data**, how could it be possible? Shouldn't it be the **Promise Object** of the second $http???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) (spoiler: they're not)

Comment: @Bergi you are right. i just checked the question and found they are quite similar. but how could i mark it as duplicated and link the question you mentioned?

Comment: You could have [flagged your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), as you can't yet [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). Alternatively, you might have accepted a duplicate suggestion by another community member. I didn't make one (I only commented) as it would've closed the question immediately - as I now have done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you return a promise from a promise `.then(…)` callback, the promise library will automatically wait for the inner promise to resolve, and will then resolve the returned promise with that value.

In other words, if you make a promise of a promise, you will get its inner value back.

This is part of the beauty of promises; you can reduce nesting by taking advantage of this feature and chaining your promises:

```
var promise = $http.get('/xxx').then(function(response1) {
    return $http.get('/yyy');
}).then(function(response2) {
    return response2.data;
});
```

For more details, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/).

Comment: Thanks! Is it the principle for general Promise (for example Promise in ES6), or it's just an implementation of angular's $q ?

Comment: @Demonbane: This is explicitly stated in the spec.  Read https://promisesaplus.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt doesn't work because you're not returning the promise returned by the inner http call. Instead it is returning a derived promise from the first then. The derived promise is resolved with a value of undefined.

Some more info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained